# WebApi using EF EPPlus returning gibberish in exce

Tags: asp.net-web-api, epplus

I am trying to use EPPlus in my EF WebApi to return data in a excel workbook.
The call to webserver gets made successfully, but when my browser opens the excel doc... all the content is gibberish.

This is my webapi

```
        private xxxV003Context db = new xxxV003Context();

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        //MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.Content = new StreamContent(ExcelSheet());
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Orders.xlsx";
        return response;
    }

    public List<Client> Orders()
    {
        List<Client> tList = new List<Client>();
        using (db)
        {
            tList.Add(new Client { ClientID = 50, ClientName = "testName1" });
            tList.Add(new Client { ClientID = 51, ClientName = "testName2" });
        }
        return tList;
    }

    public MemoryStream ExcelSheet()
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Orders");
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(Orders(), false);
            package.Save();
            var stream = new MemoryStream(package.GetAsByteArray());
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

here is the screenshot
[image]

NEW ERROR MESSAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog     xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error125800_03.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Orders   (2).xlsx'</summary>
-<additionalInfo>
<info>Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this    workbook may have been repaired or discarded.</info>
</additionalInfo>
</recoveryLog>
```

Comment: It may not be the issue per se, but EPPlus generates .xlsx files not .xls files - try using the .xlsx extension (I am skeptical that this is the only issue here but certainly needs fixing)

Comment: @Stewart_R ahh.. so I changed it to .xlsx, now it opens and I see the data, but I get a excel level validation and repair... I put message above.  do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like progress! I have actually seen the same error before in one of our auto reports but, as it was an internal thing, we are just living with it for now. Doesn't seem to cause any problems.

Comment: yes progress!  thanks for pointing out my mistake on the xls vs xlsx!!!

Comment: Try using `response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());`.  So instead of returning a `Stream` simply return the byte array from your `ExcelSheet` function.

Comment: @Ernie, how do I put the byte array in the response?

Comment: I got it working with byte array... what are the benefits of returning byte or memorystream?

Comment: If it fixed the error then that would be the benefit.  But if you get the same error (talking about the Excel opening message) then it could be the headers need adjusting.

Comment: nope... same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPPlus creates .xlsx files - Change the file extension from `.xls` to `.xlsx`