# Exporting XLSX file with Epplus generates file with error

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, epplus

### Problem

I'm trying to send a List to an Excel file by using the LoadFromCollection method.
After I generate an XLSX file, it does not open but if I change the extension to XLS, it appears like this.

[ExcelFileError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxrWg.png)

### Code

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetExcel")]
public async Task<HttpResponse> GetExcel()
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

var stream =  new MemoryStream();
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SoftwareVersao");
    var result = await _versaoAppService.Selecionar();
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(result);
    ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
    excelPackage.SaveAs(stream);
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "SoftwareVersao.xlsx");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

return HttpContext.Current.Response;
}
```

This code generates a corrupted XLSX file if I change the lines below it generates the above image.

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "SoftwareVersao.xls");
```

### Attempts

I've made several attempts.

- I used HttpResponseMessage instead of HttpResponse
- I used a blank template in creating the file
- I changed the enconding
- I used several code snippets

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I forgot to implement?

### Update

I found this question and now could generate the XLSX file, but I'm having the same problem that the author of the question, where Excel have to repair the file.

[WebApi using EF EPPlus returning gibberish in exce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919185/webapi-using-ef-epplus-returning-gibberish-in-exce)

Comment: What if you do `HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray()));` instead?

Comment: @Ernie I put that inside the using, I removed the using, but the problem still continues.